# How do i get rid of a blue border surrounding my button? For Java GUI

Tags: java, swing, focus, border, jbutton

Because it wont let me add an image - new account

[image: Monster]

This is utilizing the Java GUI
The above image is an image pasted onto a button, I've tried to make the button transparent so that the user can't see it but I can't seem to get rid of this blue border.
Code I have so far

```
    boss2 = new JButton();    //declared the static button earlier on in the code

    boss2.setSize(300, 300);
    boss2.setLocation(315, 200);
    boss2.setIcon(new ImageIcon("dragon.gif"));
    boss2.setRolloverIcon(new ImageIcon("dragon.gif"));
    boss2.setOpaque(false);
    boss2.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    boss2.setBorder(null);
```

Is there a way to get rid of the blue border surrounding my image?

edit - sorry for the earlier mishap, uploaded the wrong file

Comment: Do you mean the window frame?

Comment: There is no blue boarder, and `setBoarder(null);` will take care of that if there were.

Comment: About the only other possible suggestion maybe to include `boss2.setFocusPainted(false);`, but honestly, I still have no idea what your actual problem is...

Comment: Sorry, the earlier image was when i clicked out of the window - sent the wrong link, but the boss2.setfocuspainted solved the problem, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest that what you are seeing is the focus rectangle, used to "highlight" the button as having keyboard focus.

You can use `boss2.setFocusPainted(false);` to stop it from been painted.

Answer (score 1):

To not have a boarder drawn for a JButton (assuming that you are using [javax.swing.JButton](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html)) you can simply do:

```
boss2.setBorderPainted(false);
```

Comment: You would think so, but try using `boss2.setBorder(null);` and see what you get ;)